# CarouFredSel - turn off infinite scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caroufredsel

I have a horizontal scrolling carousel:

```
    _gotoNext: function (that) {

        //tjobbe - put funciton here to check if there is anything else after the last slide, then stop / disable the gotonext. must only scroll one if only one is available (or 2). same for go to prev
        that.$element.find('.mediaCarousel').trigger("next", false);
    },

    //This method tells the mediaCarousel to go to the previous slide.
    _gotoPrev: function(that, callback) {
        that.$element.find('.mediaCarousel').trigger("prev", false);
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YVCTx/

I need it to STOP or at least disable the next button when it gets to the last item. If there is an un-even number I also need it to only scroll one or two items, or let it do the full three.

**My current code doesn't seem to be paying attention to the built in "infinite: true (or false)" option.**

For example, I have 7 items at the moment, and I scroll 3 at a time. I'd like to stop at the third scroll, so that the second scroll only goes as for as the items in the list.

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: Is this an existing plugin or did you create it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you mentioned caroufredsel. http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel It has options for `infinite` and `circular`. Did you try these?

Comment: I did, just edited my question - sorry. My current code doesn't seem to be listening to this. have tried both true and false for infinite.

Comment: So what settings did you use? Did you see: *Note: It is possible to create a non-circular, infinite carousel, but it is not possible to create a circular, non-infinite carousel.*

Comment: I tried both:circular: true and infinite: true, as well as false for each and it made no change whatsoever to the scrolling, and I cannot figure out why?

Comment: Show us your code! How do you set these options? If you can, provide a jsfiddle with your code and a working carousel (include the plugin somehow as an external resource).

Comment: There's a jsfiddle in the original question, but here you go ;o) http://jsfiddle.net/YVCTx/

Comment: That's not the code we need. Where do you set these options?

Comment: Lines 10 - 40 ish in that jsfiddle - the js pane.

Comment: You're not providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Sorry to insist but: there is no point having a non-working fiddle. How can we test that? Further to that, your example does not reflect the use of `infinite` or `circular` options.

Comment: I'll try and get a working jsFiddle up here, but the problem is it's from a large website and getting it to work on jsfiddle is a nightmare.

As for the circular / infinite options you mentioned - I see they're not in the code but I have tried them. Thanks everyone for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a circular and an infinite option which you can set.

I would imagine one of those would do what you want (most probably the infinite one):

```
$('#carousel').carouFredSel({
    circular: true,         // Determines whether the carousel should be circular.
    infinite: true,         // Determines whether the carousel should be infinite. Note: It is possible to create a non-circular, infinite carousel, but it is not possible to create a circular, non-infinite carousel.
    responsive: false,      // Determines whether the carousel should be responsive. If true, the items will be resized to fill the carousel.
    direction: "left",      // The direction to scroll the carousel. Possible values: "right", "left", "up" or "down".
    width: null,            // The width of the carousel. Can be null (width will be calculated), a number, "variable" (automatically resize the carousel when scrolling items with variable widths), "auto" (measure the widest item) or a percentage like "100%" (only applies on horizontal carousels)
    height: null,           // The height of the carousel. Can be null (width will be calculated), a number, "variable" (automatically resize the carousel when scrolling items with variable heights), "auto" (measure the tallest item) or a percentage like "100%" (only applies on vertical carousels)
    align: "center",        // Whether and how to align the items inside a fixed width/height. Possible values: "center", "left", "right" or false.
    padding: null,          // Padding around the carousel (top, right, bottom and left). For example: [10, 20, 30, 40] (top, right, bottom, left) or [0, 50] (top/bottom, left/right).
    synchronise: null,      // Selector and options for the carousel to synchronise: [string selector, boolean inheritOptions, boolean sameDirection, number deviation] For example: ["#foo2", true, true, 0]
    cookie: false,          // Determines whether the carousel should start at its last viewed position. The cookie is stored until the browser is closed. Can be a string to set a specific name for the cookie to prevent multiple carousels from using the same cookie.
    onCreate: null          // Function that will be called after the carousel has been created. Receives a map of all data.
});
```

Source: [documentation](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel)

Comment: Sorry, should have added that my current code seems to ignore infinite true / false. Just edited my question.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to just be the caroufredsel plugin. Could you update it with some content, then I'll have a look.